# How do Search Engines Segment Against Locale?

Tags: seo, google, web-hosting, search-engines, google-search-console

Assume I run a multi-lingual website. If I had a Spanish section, it should be included in Spanish-segmented search engines such as

- Google Spain
- Google Peru
- Google El Salvador

and excluded in the others. Likewise, even though the website would have content in Chinese, multilingual countries such as Singapore should feature content in their main language (English in this case).

What is the best approach to ensure the appropriate language is associated with Google's search indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, this popped up into my mind the other day, so I did some research.

Google bots are almost exclusively crawling from the US. They index content based on natural language processing and will do all the language configuration for you. There should be little to no requirement on your part for your geographic segmentation to work. From there, basic SEO will rank which content shows up first (use keywords like Singapore if you want to segment those users, for instance).

Comment: thanks, I had a hunch that the bots were located in the US